# IntelliJ cannot resolve symbol Subscribe kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I have the next project in IntelliJ, the problem is that `Subscribe` inside `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream` appears red, and it throws `Cannot resolve symbol Subscribe` but I have added all the kafka-spark libraries:

```
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent

  def startMetaInfoSubscriber(ssc: StreamingContext, kafkaParams: Map[String, Object], metaInfoTopic: String) {
    // Set a unique Kafka group identifier to metaInformationStream (each stream requires a unique group ID)
    val metaInformationKafkaParamas = kafkaParams ++ Map[String, Object]("group.id" -> RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10).toUpperCase)

    KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      ssc,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, String](metaInfoTopic, metaInformationKafkaParamas)
    ).foreachRDD(metaInfoRDD =>
      if (!metaInfoRDD.isEmpty()) {
        println("Saving MetaInformation")
        metaInfoRDD
//        metaInfoRDD.write.mode("append").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(s"hdfs://172.16.8.162:8020/user/sparkload/assetgroup/prueba-kafka")
      } else {
        println("There is not any message for topic 'tu-topic'")
      }
    )
  }
```

And the next is my pom.xml:

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
<scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
<spark.version>2.3.0</spark.version>
<src.dir>src/main/scala</src.dir>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka_2.11 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

When I try to compile, I have the next error:

```
[ERROR] C:\Users\agomez\Desktop\spark-base\spark-kafka-tfm\src\main\scala\spark_load\EjemploApp.scala:90: error: overloaded method value Subscribe with alternatives:
[ERROR]   (topics: java.util.Collection[String],kafkaParams: java.util.Map[String,Object])org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy[String,String] <and>
[ERROR]   (topics: java.util.Collection[String],kafkaParams: java.util.Map[String,Object],offsets: java.util.Map[org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition,java.lang.Long])org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy[String,String] <and>
[ERROR]   (topics: Iterable[String],kafkaParams: scala.collection.Map[String,Object])org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy[String,String] <and>
[ERROR]   (topics: Iterable[String],kafkaParams: scala.collection.Map[String,Object],offsets: scala.collection.Map[org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition,scala.Long])org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy[String,String]
[ERROR]  cannot be applied to (String, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Object])
[ERROR]       Subscribe[String, String](metaInfoTopic, metaInformationKafkaParamas)
[ERROR]                ^
[ERROR] one error found
```

Comment: Ignore intelliJ as long as your project compiles and builds fine.

Comment: When I try to compile I have an error because the Subscribe. I have edited the question with the error I have when trying to compile, please check the question again.

Comment: `metaInformationKafkaParamas` is a `Map` and you are trying to tell the compiler that it is a `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first parameter of `Subscribe()` should be Collection of topics

So you need to pass multiple topics as `Seq[Strings]` or `Array[Strings]`.
If you have single topic simply pass it as `Seq(metaInfoTopic)`

```
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
    ssc,
    PreferConsistent,
    Subscribe[String, String](Seq(metaInfoTopic), metaInformationKafkaParamas)
)
```

Hope this helps!